# NSIS Confirm Uninstallation of app

Tags: python, nsis, messagebox, uninstallation

Currently creating an uninstaller for my app. The uninstaller doesn't show any confirmation message before uninstalling. Is there a way to prompt the user for confirmation (I'm hoping for a default message or something so it can be localized easily, instead of having to create localization files for just that) ?

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions:

1) Using standard NSIS pages

Prompt the user in uninstaller init function

```
function un.onInit
   ...

   #Verify the uninstaller - last chance to back out
   MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "Permanantly remove ${APPNAME}?" IDOK next
      Abort

   ...
functionEnd
```

Example can be found [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/A_simple_installer_with_start_menu_shortcut_and_uninstaller)

2) Using Modern User Interface (MUI)

Set uninstaller confirmation page

```
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
```

Example can be found [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Examples/Modern%20UI/Basic.nsi)